# Dev Tools console refreshes to fast and can't see the error with Nuxt 3 and Supabase

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, google-chrome-devtools, supabase

I have this strange issue with my Nuxt project. I have a button for signing in with email and password using Supabase.

```
    const signIn = async () => {
    const { data, error } = await client.auth.signInWithPassword({ email: email.value, password: password.value })
    //emits('submit')
    console.log(data)
 
    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return;
    }     
}
```

I get an error here, but I can't see it in the Chrome Dev Tools console, because it appears only for a fraction of a second and then it refreshes to the following 2 lines related to Suspense and Nuxt dev tools:

[image]

Being totally knew with web development, I don't understand, if this is an issue with Chrome, in my Nuxt 3 project or what ?

Any ideas ?

Comment: Debug it: set a breakpoint on that line in devtools so execution will pause.

Comment: Is the page refreshing and resetting the console perhaps? Choose "keep logs" in the console settings.

Comment: I tried to debug, but it crashes after the first line, it doesn't go further, so I suspect its something related to Supabase.

Comment: Apparently this refresh in the console comes from the <input>, the moment I write a letter after the '@' character in the email, it triggers the refresh. not sure why yet. For example: blabla@ does not trigger a refresh, but blabla@y will trigger it.